# Java .size() function is not showing actual size of the ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

So I'm kinda new to java programming. I was given a task to write a program to calculate greatest common divisor by decomposition into prime factors. The problem is when I started using size() function to determine size of the ArrayList, it is not showing the actual size of array.
Do you have any idea what am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?
Thank you for any kind of help.
Please, don't mind any other wrong calculations.

```
 public static int NWD(int x, int y) {
    int res = 1;
    if (y == 0) {
        return x;
    }
    ArrayList<Integer> x_pf_list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> y_pf_list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int i = 2 ; i < Math.max(x, y) ; i++ )
    {
        while (x%i == 0) 
        {
            x_pf_list.add(i);
            x /= i;
        }
        while (y%i == 0) 
        {
            y_pf_list.add(i);
            y /= i;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("X table size: "+x_pf_list.size()+" and here's how it looks: ");
    for (int s = 0 ; s < x_pf_list.size(); s++)
    {
        System.out.println(x_pf_list.get(s));
    }
    int size = y_pf_list.size();
    System.out.println("Y table size: "+size+" and here's how it looks: ");
    for (int f = 0 ; f < y_pf_list.size(); f++)
    {
        System.out.println(y_pf_list.get(f));
    } ...
```

[Eclipse screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9gD7.png)

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Post actual code, not an image of your code. And the size() method will print the size of the ArrayList. If it is not what you expect then you have a logic problem to debug.

Comment: Try to print size with iteration and track the behaviour

Comment: @camickr done, sorry for trouble

Comment: @VarunSharma I am pretty sure I did it, as shown on the image above. It shows all the array elements.

Comment: @janki3l Looks fine to me. Are you sure that last didits are from given code? Tyr to print smth like `-----` after the last loop and check that there're no additional numbers after it.

Comment: You can just print the list to display it: `System.out.println(x_pf_list);`. `println` will use the `toString` method of the object.

Comment: It works fine for me. I agree with Oleg's suggestion.

Comment: @oleg.cherednik now I see where I made mistake, it worked. Thank you!